# Observable.just vs Single in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava and RxAndroid and trying to understand the difference between `Observable.just` and `Single`. It looks like each is designed to emit one item for its observer.

Here is the code of my simple Android activity with two buttons. The first button creates an `Observable`, and the second button creates a `Single`:

```
findViewById(R.id.just).setOnClickListener(view -> Observable.just("item").subscribe(
        new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "just onSubscribe");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "just s=" + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "just e=" + e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "just onComplete");
            }
        }));

findViewById(R.id.single).setOnClickListener(
        view -> Single.create((SingleOnSubscribe<String>) e -> {
        })
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "single onSubscribe");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String o) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "single onSuccess");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "single onError", e);
                    }
                }));
```

When I press the "Just" button, `onSubscribe`, `onNext`, and `onComplete` are called.

When I press the "Single" button, only `SingleObserver#onSubscibe` is called, and `SingleObserver#onSuccess` is not.

The versions of RxJava and RxAndroid in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
// Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working as expected. With the first you emit item but not in the second.

You need to change to

```
 findViewById(R.id.single).setOnClickListener(
    view -> Single.create((SingleOnSubscribe<String>) e -> {
            if(!e.isDisposed())
            e.onSuccess("item");
    })
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "single onSubscribe");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String o) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "single onSuccess" + " "+o);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "single onError", e);
                }
            }));
```

Now you should see "item" in `onSuccess`.

Say you want to do some operation then return a string you would do as suggested above. Suppose your operation fails you can then do `e.onError(new IOException());)` , now you should see the error in `onError`

Comment: OK, thanks. But the bottom line is that they are both designed to emit one event, right?

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0.  check the docs i think the docs has a better explanation

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev yes. and it depends on in what cases you need to use Observable/Flowable/Single/Maybe/Completable. Check this an example of usecase of RxJava with Room https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757

Comment: The `Single.create()` javadoc even has an example: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#create-io.reactivex.SingleOnSubscribe-